# the Facebook comment popup on like gets hidden behind m website menu and other elements. how can I have it visible on top

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I am trying to figure out on how to make the facebook comment popup box be visible and does not get hidden by the other age elements like menu and my javascript scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try nesting it in a div with css-style position: absolute and/or high z-index (like 999).